# Weird Texturing Problem in Eevee Render Engine

Tags: rendering, animation, image, eevee-render-engine

This is a persistent problem for me while using Eevee to render still images and animations.

Recently as I’ve been rendering out images and animations, both still images and all frames of my animations display these weirdly textured blocky effects in the final results.
[image][image][image]

When I save these images or animation frames or even videos to my computer, these weird visual effects stay present.

I’m not sure if this is a problem with my computer or Blender itself. Cycles has no apparent issues. I’ve tried lowering and increasing samples or adding a material but whatever fails to render stays in the final output.

I’ve searched to see if anyone else has this issue but I can’t find anything. If anyone could point me to a possible solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Consider sharing your .blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look :). Without that, it’s just guessing.

Comment: Material > Settings looks for Blend Mode, looks like an alpha blend problem.